# Retrieve azure service bus messages using google functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, azureservicebus

So the scenario is that there is a ML model running in google cloud and the input to that needs to be send in form of an azure service bus message. Is this even possible?

I need to implement a handler (google cloud function) to retrieve messages from azure service bus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure service bus’ SDK and write your own code to retrieve it. You can go through these [Azure Service Bus Client library for python samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-python/servicebus-samples/), which may help you in writing your code.

You will need to trigger the function whenever you want to retrieve the messages from the service bus, to do that either you can use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs) to set a trigger timer or have Azure side trigger the HTTP URL of Cloud Functions.